# Web Optimization $(window).focus()

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

My question is about the javascript function window.onfocus().

Does it give us a way to optimize our webpage or will the browser handle this when I change the tab?

E.g. If I have an autoplay slider, is it better for performance to handle this function and pause the loop when I change the tab or is it not relevant?

Comment: What is autoplay slider? Do You want to do something with a page on onfocus event?

Comment: I want to say a slider running in a bucle, if is better to stop it when the tab is on blur, or it's not necesary?